# Android UIAutomation Instrumentation NoSuchMethod Exception

Tags: android, ui-automation, instrumentation

Any idea why I get this exceptions. Its supposed to be very straight forward and simple. It compiles without any errors or warnings. At run time it throws exception.

```
            Instrumentation im = new Instrumentation();
            UiAutomation myVar = im.getUiAutomation();
            myVar.injectInputEvent(evntDown,false);
```

Here's the exception.

```
01-26 11:59:17.344  17742-17742/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.app.Instrumentation.getUiAutomation
        at com.infostretch.automateme.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:51)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UIAutomation` was included in `API 18`. `NoSuchMethod` Exception occurs when you try to access/use a class/method that is not supported on OS/API version you are currently running the app on.

Comment: So - I got 4.2.1 on phone which means its api 17. Probably you are right.. Slightly off topic question, my carier does not provide updates for my phone, so how do I upgrade my phone to 4.3/4.4?

Comment: root it. flash a custom rom or you can just emulate the code on PC

Comment: bit skeptical to accept without trying out but most likely it could be the only cause.. so I will. thx for your help.